# How can I test functionality that only exists as a REST API call?

Tags: unit-test, rest-api, field-service-lightning

The only way to create a Service Report programmatically in Field Service is to call out via REST to the Actions API (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_code_samples_sr.htm).

Since you can't make real callouts from test code and have to mock everything, but there's no "internal" way to create a Service Report, how would you approach unit testing this to ensure a Service Report would be created?

Sample code

```
public void createServiceReport()
{
    // Create HTTP request
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(url);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

    // Set the body as a JSON object
    request.setBody('{"inputs" : [ {"entityId" : "' + entityId + '","templateId" : "' +templateId + '"}]}');
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    // Parse the JSON response
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201)
    {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
            response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    }
    else
    {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: If the service report itself is handled by FSL, why do you need to test it? If you want to test that your code is passing the correct data for FSL to use, you can use a mock callout in your unit test to check the payload it receives it accurate.

Comment: Client request is to automatically generate a Service Report when the Work Order status  goes to completed.  Test intent is to ensure it is created and attached to the work order

Comment: If that is standard FSL behaviour, why are you testing it?

Comment: Creating a service report automatically is not standard behaviour - that's the part I'm testing, did my rest callout code work. or not

Comment: Phrasing things a different way - what would valid test assertions be to ensure that when they try this in Production, it has a good chance of working?

Comment: If you want to verify that your callout has the right data, you can mock the callout and have it assert on what it receives.

Comment: I agree with what Phil W. says, that shouldn't be tested with an Apex test - If you'd want to test the full workflow then we're talking about end-to-end tests. In a company I worked for we used capybara for these kind of automations (and you'd need a development / sandbox with field service enabled to run these kind of tests - not the production one)...

Comment: So, no way to do an equivalent of (psuedocode) system.assert(AttachedServiceReports > 0) ?  I guess as long as I get coverage that's the best I can do then